# Set NSScrollView to not editable

Tags: objective-c, nstextview

I was wondering how to take care that my NSScrollView is not editable by the user, but i didn't find a way, there is no option in IB, nor do I find an appropriate method of the NSSCrollView class.

A previous post suggested to implement a delegate method

```
- (BOOL)textShouldBeginEditing:(NSText *)aTextObject
```

to return false, but this didn't work for me yet.
No solution was given on the previous question.

(I also tried selecting the TextView everything it doesn't display an option 'editable' i just downloaded the new Xcode so the version shouldn't be a problem)

Comment: Okay i found it i have to find the embedded text view (clickable in the top part of the scrollview) and set that one to non editable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is inside the scrollView that you want to prevent editing of?

what views have you got embedded in the scrollView? you need to find the view embedded in the scrollView that you want to prevent editing on, and call setEditable:NO on it.

Comment: what views have you got embedded in the scrollView? you need to find the view embedded in the scrollView that you want to prevent editing on, and call setEditable:NO on it.

Comment: Add that last response to the main answer ... @Samuel - Accept it! ...not to be pushy or anything...

Comment: Sorry, was busy coding again :p

Answer (score 2):

You can't make NSScrollView non-editable. You can hide scrollers with setHasVerical/HorizontalScroller: that would prevent user from scrolling.

If you have NSTextView and want to make it non-editable just send setEditable:NO to it, not the scroll view. For that you obviously need a reference to the NSTextView or use NSScrollViews -documentView.

Comment: How do you access the TextView itself? In the storyboard interface builder, the TextView object is wrapped in an NSScrollView by default.